# Creating abstract animation video

Tags: osx

I'm trying to find some Mac OS X software to create some "abstract" video as an advertisement — made up of animations, pictures, etc.

An example of the style of video I'm talking about is Apple's [Intention video](http://youtu.be/VpZmIiIXuZ0).

Any help/pointers would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I haven't used it but it might worth trying [Synfig Studio](http://www.synfig.org/). It is free.